# Getting "No input file specified" when running a search query

Tags: nominatim

I installed successfully nominatim and testing it with `nominatim serve` returns correct answers.

When I try it directly from the command line with
`nominatim search --query 'Avd Ricardo Soriano, Marbella, Spain' --format geocodejson`

I receive this:

```
2021-11-07 23:43:51: Using project directory: /srv/nominatim
2021-11-07 23:43:51: Status: 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.24
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

No input file specified.
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong and how to fix `No input file specified.` . Google really doesn't help me.

**My question:**
What to do in order to fix this error and get the result as I would have ran it from as a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*OK, this was really very stupid of me but now I understand:*

You must **always** execute ([it's also mentioned in the documentation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Import/)) `nominatim`
from the project directory or provide the `--project-dir` parameter.

So, in my case this should have been the correct usage:

```
nominatim search                                   \
    --project-dir /srv/nominatim/nominatim-planet  \
    --query 'Avd Ricardo Soriano, Marbella, Spain' \
    --format geocodejson --polygon-output geojson
```

It works like a charm.